# How to make flexible widget from changing the window size?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scrolledtext

I want to make my `scrolledtext` to change it's size with the window size

```py
# import GUI
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext


# create instance
win = tk.Tk()

# title name
win.title("Notepad ver.1.0")

# resizable option
win.resizable(True, True)

# geometry
win.geometry("1900x1000")

# frame 1
frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text='')
frame1.grid(column=0, row=0)
# some lables are inside frame1
ttk.Label(frame1, text='Hello World').grid(column=0, row=0)


# frame2
frame2 = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text='')
# set the width and height of your frame as desired using ipadx and ipady
frame2.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky=tk.S, ipadx=880, ipady=370)
# disable grid propagation to prevent resizing on font size changes
frame2.grid_propagate(False)

# scrolled text
ScrWidth = 0
ScrHight = 0
scr = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame2, wrap=tk.WORD, width=ScrWidth, height=ScrHight)
scr.pack(side='left', fill="both", expand=True, ipadx=0, ipady=0)
scr.config(font='Arial, 10')
scr.grid_propagate(False)

# start GUI
win.mainloop()
```

I tried to ask ChatGpt to do it and also google it and found that

```py
win.bind("<Configure>", function)
```

will make my code work but it made my code more glitchy.

The glitch:
[The Glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpGL3.png)

Thank You for everyone for helping me!

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot or describe what do you mean by "more glitchy"?

Comment: @radeklat Sure I will edit my post and upload it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the instance of `ScrolledText` (`scr`) to be resized whenever the window is resized, you need to:

- configure its parent `frame2` to use all the available space by setting `sticky="nsew"` in `frame2.grid(...)`
- allocate all available space to row 7 and column 0 where `frame2` is put by calling `win.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)` and `win.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`

Below is the updated code:

```py
# import GUI
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext


# create instance
win = tk.Tk()

# title name
win.title("Notepad ver.1.0")

# resizable option
win.resizable(True, True)

# geometry
win.geometry("1900x1000")

# frame 1
frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text='')
frame1.grid(column=0, row=0)
# some lables are inside frame1
ttk.Label(frame1, text='Hello World').grid(column=0, row=0)

win.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
win.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# frame2
frame2 = ttk.LabelFrame(win, text='')
# set the width and height of your frame as desired using ipadx and ipady
### changed sticky option to "nsew"
frame2.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky="nsew", ipadx=880, ipady=370)
# disable grid propagation to prevent resizing on font size changes
#frame2.grid_propagate(False)  # it is not necessary

# scrolled text
ScrWidth = 0
ScrHight = 0
scr = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame2, wrap=tk.WORD, width=ScrWidth, height=ScrHight)
scr.pack(side='left', fill="both", expand=True, ipadx=0, ipady=0)
scr.config(font='Arial, 10')
#scr.grid_propagate(False)  # it is not necessary

# start GUI
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you 'acw1668' it is nice of you to fix my whole code for me!